# Why is git stealth-merging and duplicating code?

Tags: git, merge

Yesterday, I merged a local development branch to my local master branch, after which I planned to push to remote master. I run git commands from git bash, then switch to Visual Studio to handle merge conflicts.

My first clue something was wrong was that there were multiple merge conflicts highlighting large chunks of code in which there were actually zero differences. Text highlighting was also mysteriously gone on the incoming branch, which I'd initially assumed was a setting I'd accidentally changed or an update, but given everything else, maybe it's related.

Then I noticed an instance where a string was `abcd` in master and `abcd - efg` in the incoming branch, and it just... stealth-merged. It didn't flag a conflict and ask which I wanted; it just silently chose which to keep (and chose the wrong one, to boot).

Then I noticed an `if` block of code was duplicated in the merge. In the course of troubleshooting all these things (and before I noticed the duplication), I'd merged the branch to another local branch to see if the same problems persisted, and this `if` block showed up there 3 times, so it duplicated once with each merge. In case it's not clear what I mean:

Pre-merge:

```
// code
if (condition)
{
  // do things
}
// code
```

Post-merge:

```
// code
if (condition)
{
  // do things
}
if (condition)
{
  // do things
}
// code
```

Then I spotted *another* instance of a stealth-merge: the changing of a variable name. In one branch it was all lowercase, in the other branch it was camelCase, and it just silently chose the lowercase version on the variable declaration and camelCase wherever it was used.

Then I spotted another duplication, but this time of the entire function. I even put it in a text comparer to be sure and they were identical. Note that this duplication and the `if` block duplication were on subsequent lines to the original.

As you can imagine, I am thoroughly confused by this point. This is not normal git behavior. I'm not half bad with git and my coworker is even better, and we're both in the *"what the actual ****"* stage with this. Then this morning I come to work, hoping it magically resolved overnight (spoiler alert: it didn't), and spot *another* duplicate function, but this one is separated from the original by a lot of code instead of being right after it. Weird. So I started comparing them and realize the duplicate is really an old version of the function. From **weeks** ago. With multiple commits between.

Troubleshooting: rebooted computer, rebooted VS, tried merging to another branch, tried reinstalling git, tried recloning repo and merging branches with reinstalled git. Odd behavior persisted. I tried googling about the stealth merge, with limited success, and about the duplicating, with none of the answers matching my problem.

What is happening?! Why is this happening?! What do I do about it? Please help!

Comment: Do you have anything in your `.gitattributes` file, such as a `merge=union` entry anywhere?

Comment: If a string only _changed_ in the branch, but remained unchanged in master (but still _different_), then Git is doing its job and applying the _changes_ from the branch to your merge target. It is only a conflict if the same line was changed in both branches. No stealth-merging happening here (but difficult to tell without seeing actual commands and commits).

Comment: As for the duplicated code: maybe you resolved the conflict with Visual Studio and chose both sides of the conflict?

Comment: @bk2204 No, no `merge=union` anywhere, only `merge = refs/heads/[branchname]`. @knittl I'm not sure I follow. I changed the string in the branch, I'm merging that branch into master, it kept the version in master so ignored the change and didn't ask which version I wanted. You're saying that's the correct behavior? Re duplicated code, if that happened, it wasn't a choice I made, i.e., maybe VS auto-did that?

Comment: @tiffanie yes, if a line was changed in a branch, but wasn't touched on master, then merging that branch will bring the change in. _Of course_ that's the expected behavior. Otherwise, what good would be `git merge` if you had to choose for every single change again whether or not you want to pick it?

Comment: @tiffanie another possibility for your "duplicated code" is that you are seeing the actual merge conflicts. They are usually enclosed in conflict markers (`>>>>>`, `=====`, `<<<<<` and `||||||||` with _diff3_ conflict style) – perhaps you removed those, thinking they were some kind of garbage? Or maybe Visual Studio is hiding those from you?

Comment: @knittl that's what I want to happen! I'm not sure where I'm miscommunicating? It's **keeping** the version in master and **ignoring** the change in the branch I'm merging.

Comment: @knittl the duplicated code is still there after merging is complete, as indicated by lack of errors in VS caused by the conflict markers and by `git status` and by being allowed to commit/push in bash.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236952/discussion-between-knittl-and-tiffanie).

Comment: There is no such thing as "stealth merging". It's just a matter of understand what a merge is. If you look at the diffs between the merge-base and the two branches being merged, you will see the contributions each branch is making to your code and everything will be clear. As it is, you're not telling us enough for a detailed explanation to be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using git rebase instead of git merge? It will show you the conflicts and this might be what's happening. I could be keeping both copies and duplicating it.

Comment: I can see the conflicts with git merge too, that's why I use VS to handle the merge. I tried git rebase, per your suggestion, and it did the same thing :/

Comment: Are the commits duplicated also? or is it just the code?

Comment: had the same thing happening with git rebase, some conflicts are handled automatically